# MySQL transaction - roll back on any exception

Tags: mysql, transactions, rollback

Is it possible to roll back automatically if any error occurs on a list of MySQL commands?

For example something along the lines of:

```
begin transaction;

insert into myTable values1 ...
insert into myTable values2 ...;  -- will throw an error

commit;
```

Now, on execute I want the whole transaction to fail, and therefore I should **NOT** see values1 in myTable.
But unfortunately the table is being populated with values1 even though the transaction has errors.

Any ideas how I make it to roll back? (again, on any error)?

Comment: Have you considered using Handlers? [13.6.7.2. DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use [13.6.7.2. DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) in the following way:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_fail`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `tablea` (`date`) VALUES (NOW());
    INSERT INTO `tableb` (`date`) VALUES (NOW());
    INSERT INTO `tablec` (`date`) VALUES (NOW()); -- FAIL
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

For a complete example, check the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ea00/1).

Comment: my question is, Is this stored procedure is going to be persisted in database forever?.

Comment: @MDaniyal Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) .Do you think it is a good idea that we save a new stored procedure for every new script? as we have 10 to 15 scripts per release so we would have hundreds of stored procedures.

Comment: If the exception occurs in the 1st `INSERT`, wouldn't MySQL do the 2nd and 3rd ones, leading sometimes to unexpected results?

Comment: @Xenos No, though time will be wasted. If either of the first two queries fails, `_rollback` is still set to 1 and so the function will execute `ROLLBACK;` instead of `COMMIT;`.  However, the following queries will still execute (_within_ the transaction) only to be ultimately rolled back later. It really baffles me that MySQL chose this continue-on-error behavior. Contrast this to PostgreSQL, which places the transaction in a failed state, guarantees all future queries in the transaction will fail (except `ROLLBACK TO`) and will implicitly rollback on commit.

Comment: I wrote it ,but not working: the second line should generate an error because ID =1 exists in DB `DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE prod()
BEGIN
    DECLARE _rollback BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET _rollback = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO table1 values (2, 'B');
    INSERT INTO table1 values  (1, 'A');
    IF _rollback THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL prod();

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS prod;`

Comment: @MalusJan: Can you give more information?. In the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb6202f09a82a9f037716f28afa7df2f) everything works as expected.

Comment: @wchiquito I created a temporary table in mysql (table1) with 2 fields (id --> pk, name), I insert (1, 'Text') to database and after that I ran the above query. But it inserts (2, 'B').

Comment: @wchiquito I found the problem. The table engine should be InnoDB

Comment: @anyone is this method / syntax only possible inside a stored proc ? how would you write transaction commit / rollback within a script only, to be executed by a client (say, HeidiSQL or Workbench) ?

Comment: Why using CONTINUE HANDLER for exception ?
Why not EXIT HANDLER ?

Comment: This didn't work for me, it raised an error and issued a ROLLBACK, but for some reason didn't actually roll the transaction back.

Comment: How to do the same without persisting the `stored procedure` in DB ? without even using SP, is it possible ?

Comment: Simplest and best answer

Answer (score 32):

You could use EXIT HANDLER if you for example need to SIGNAL a specific SQL EXCEPTION in your code. For instance:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_fail`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;  -- rollback any changes made in the transaction
        RESIGNAL;  -- raise again the sql exception to the caller
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
    insert into myTable values1 ...
    IF fail_condition_meet THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom error detected.', MYSQL_ERRNO = 2000;
    END IF;
    insert into myTable values2 ...  -- this will not be executed
    COMMIT; -- this will not be executed
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Im using 5.2. RESIGNAL seems to have been added in 5.5. Any suggestions for how I can get the error message using 5.2?

Comment: In case you need to log the exception: ROLLBACK will reset all the exception details, so you should set some session variables BEFORE ROLLBACK and pass them to the logging procedure AFTER ROLLBACK and before RESIGNAL for example:   https://gist.github.com/0x49D1/bbc73d9d59aafd16ced01e145c3b34b0

Answer (score 8):

The above solution are good but to make it even simpler

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_fail`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;  -- rollback any error in the transaction
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
    insert into myTable values1 ...
    insert into myTable values2 ...  -- Fails
    COMMIT; -- this will not be executed
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```