# PHP/MySQL - How to use MySQL BEGIN/COMMIT with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was wondering how to use a MySQL BEGIN/COMMIT with a PDO.
I've read that it's best to create a query that either inserts all data or none at all to provide 'consistency' in the database
Here's my code

```
$query = $db -> prepare 
                        ("
                        BEGIN;
                        INSERT INTO chat (chat_id,msg,datetime) 
                        VALUES (:cid,:msg,:datetime)
                        INSERT INTO chat_connect (chat_id,sender_id,receiver_id)
                        VALUES (:cid2,:sender_id,:receiver_id);
                        COMMIT;
                        ");
$query -> execute(array(
            "cid" => $cid,
            "msg" => $msg,
            "datetime" => $datetime,
            "sender_id" => $getid,
            "receiver_id" => $frid,
            "cid2" => $cid
            ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction syntax:

> START TRANSACTION
>       [transaction_characteristic [, transaction_characteristic] ...]
>
> transaction_characteristic:
>       WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT   | READ WRITE   | READ ONLY
>
> BEGIN [WORK] COMMIT [WORK] [AND [NO] CHAIN] [[NO] RELEASE] ROLLBACK
>   [WORK] [AND [NO] CHAIN] [[NO] RELEASE] SET autocommit = {0 | 1}

Transaction example:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

Taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

You intend to create a `transaction` via PDO. That is not really a problem. You can do it by generating the query text accordingly:

```
$query = $db -> prepare 
                        ("
                        START TRANSACTION;
                        INSERT INTO chat (chat_id,msg,datetime) 
                        VALUES (:cid,:msg,:datetime)
                        INSERT INTO chat_connect (chat_id,sender_id,receiver_id)
                        VALUES (:cid2,:sender_id,:receiver_id);
                        COMMIT;
                        ");
$query -> execute(array(
            "cid" => $cid,
            "msg" => $msg,
            "datetime" => $datetime,
            "sender_id" => $getid,
            "receiver_id" => $frid,
            "cid2" => $cid
            ));
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905900/mysql-transaction-roll-back-on-any-exception) you can see how you can write a bullet-proof transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work [only if emulation mode is turned ON](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery).

Otherwise you have to run your queries in separate calls like this.

```
$db->query("BEGIN");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat (chat_id,msg,datetime) VALUES (:cid,:msg,:datetime)");
$stmt->execute(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat_connect (chat_id,sender_id,receiver_id)
                        VALUES (:cid2,:sender_id,:receiver_id)");
$stmt->execute(...);
$db->query("COMMIT");
```

this is a general rule dor running miltiple-query statements in PHP.

However, in case of a transaction, instead of SQL commands `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` you can use [their PDO counterparts](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php).