# What happens by default if an error occurs during a transaction in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, mariadb

Let's say you have a stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE usp_do_something (
    IN param1 INT,
    IN param2 INT,
    IN param3 INT
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT `table1` ( `ID` ) VALUES (param1);
    INSERT `table2` ( `ID` ) VALUES (param2);
    INSERT `table3` ( `ID` ) VALUES (param3);

    COMMIT;
END;
```

And then the stored procedure is called with a set of parameter values which cause one of the `INSERT` operations to fail, raising an `SQLEXCEPTION`.

There is no explicit `ROLLBACK` command in this example. Testing shows that the transaction is not committed when the SQLEXCEPTION occurs before the `COMMIT;` statement. Is the transaction implicitly rolled back when the stored procedure ends? Or will the transaction be left hanging until some kind of timeout occurs? Could this cause the stored proc to hold locks for some time after it's failed?

I know that I can explicitly trigger `ROLLBACK` on failure using `DECLARE HANDLER` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905900/mysql-transaction-roll-back-on-any-exception) but I can't find any documentation that describes what MariaDB does if a stored-procedure transaction fails before reaching a `COMMIT` statement without any explicit `ROLLBACK`.

Is there a MariaDB/MySQL log or transaction state table that I could look at to see what the server is doing with this transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a stored procedure fails execution is aborted, but the transaction **IS NOT FINALIZED**.

See an example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (ID INT CHECK (id < 100));
> CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table1;
> CREATE TABLE table3 LIKE table1;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE usp_do_something (
>     IN param1 INT,
>     IN param2 INT,
>     IN param3 INT
> )
> MODIFIES SQL DATA
> BEGIN
>     START TRANSACTION;
>
>     INSERT `table1` ( `ID` ) VALUES (param1);
>     INSERT `table2` ( `ID` ) VALUES (param2);
>     INSERT `table3` ( `ID` ) VALUES (param3);
>
>     COMMIT;
> END;
> ```

Insert data without errors. All data is inserted.

> ```
> CALL usp_do_something (10, 20, 30);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, '1' tablenum FROM table1 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '2' tablenum FROM table2 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '3' tablenum FROM table3 ORDER BY ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | tablenum
> -: | :-------
> 10 | 1       
> 20 | 2       
> 30 | 3
> ```

Insert data with error in 2nd statement. All data before error (40) is inserted.

> ```
> CALL usp_do_something (40, 500, 60);
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'table2_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, '1' tablenum FROM table1 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '2' tablenum FROM table2 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '3' tablenum FROM table3 ORDER BY ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | tablenum
> -: | :-------
> 10 | 1       
> 20 | 2       
> 30 | 3       
> 40 | 1
> ```

Insert data with error in 2nd statement. All data before error (70) is inserted. This last call may be rollbacked due to non-committed transaction. But the data inserted in previous block (40) is committed implicitly by the transaction start and cannot be rollbacked.

> ```
> CALL usp_do_something (70, 800, 90);
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'table2_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, '1' tablenum FROM table1 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '2' tablenum FROM table2 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '3' tablenum FROM table3 ORDER BY ID;
>
> ROLLBACK;
>
> SELECT *, '1' tablenum FROM table1 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '2' tablenum FROM table2 UNION ALL
> SELECT *, '3' tablenum FROM table3 ORDER BY ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | tablenum
> -: | :-------
> 10 | 1       
> 20 | 2       
> 30 | 3       
> 40 | 1       
> 70 | 1       
>
> ✓
>
> ID | tablenum
> -: | :-------
> 10 | 1       
> 20 | 2       
> 30 | 3       
> 40 | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6ae20f8076fbe8fec357ae2d63fa7ef)*

Comment: Thanks, that's extremely illuminating. Can you point me to any reference material I can read up on to understand better what state I should expect the database to be in while transactions are unfinalised/pending? 

I was surprised to see the value of (40) being visible after the first stored proc call; I didn't realise that there would be an implicit COMMIT when the new transaction started.
In my earlier testing invoking the stored proc via phpMyAdmin I seemed to get different results, with no partial inserts being observable. Perhaps phpMyAdmin is doing implicit rollbacks on my behalf.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum Enable MySQL General log, repeat your experiment and look for the queries sent from phpMyAdmin - you'll find additional queries, maybe those which causes committing or rollbacking. Also it is possible that phpMyAdmin simply closes one connection and opens another - connection closing (without commit) rollbacked all changes.